# Pasar datos de un datagridview a un texbox en Visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Estoy realizando una agenda en `VB.Net`. Ya tengo casi todo listo, pero hay una parte para la que necesito ayuda.

Me gustaría que, al hacer clic en el botón `Siguiente`, se mostraran en los `TextBox` los datos de un contacto almacenado en el `DataGridView` y si se vuelve a clickear el botón, se mostraran los datos del siguiente. Lo mismo para el botón `Atrás`.

A continuación, el código desarrollado hasta ahora:

```
Public Class Form1
    'Subrutina privada para Salir del Formulario
    Private Sub BotonSalir_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BotonSalir.Click
        'Finalizar Ejecucion
        End
    End Sub

    'Subrutina Privada para Mostrar u ocultar Lista de Contacto
    Private Sub BotonMostrarContactos_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BotonMostrarContactos.Click
        'Ponemos una condicion de que sí la lista de contacto está oculto, está se muestre
        If Agenda.Visible = False Then
            BotonMostrarContactos.Text = "Ocultar Contactos"
            Agenda.Visible = True
            'De lo contrario se oculte
        Else
            BotonMostrarContactos.Text = "Mostrar Contactos"
            Agenda.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub

    'Subrutina Privada para Habilitar y vaciar los textbox
    Private Sub BotonNuevo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BotonNuevo.Click
        'Los textbox Pasan de Deshabilitado (False) a Habilitado (True)
        TextBoxNombre.Enabled = True
        TextBoxTelefono.Enabled = True
        TextBoxDireccion.Enabled = True
        'Vaciar Textbox
        TextBoxNombre.Text = ""
        TextBoxTelefono.Text = ""
        TextBoxDireccion.Text = ""
    End Sub

    'Subrutina privada para Guardar Contacto
    Private Sub BotonGuardar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BotonGuardar.Click
        'Guardamos los valores de los texbox en una fila de la Agenda (DataGridView)
        Agenda.Rows.Add(TextBoxNombre.Text, TextBoxTelefono.Text, TextBoxDireccion.Text)
        MsgBox("Guardado Correctamente")

        'Deshabilitamos los Textbox
        TextBoxNombre.Enabled = False
        TextBoxTelefono.Enabled = False
        TextBoxDireccion.Enabled = False

        'y vaciamos los Textbox
        TextBoxNombre.Text = ""
        TextBoxTelefono.Text = ""
        TextBoxDireccion.Text = ""
    End Sub

    'Subrutina privada para Eliminar Contacto
    Private Sub BotonEliminar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BotonEliminar.Click
        'Le decimos que elimine una fila seleccionada de la Agenda (DataGridView)
        Agenda.Rows.Remove(Agenda.CurrentRow)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BotonSiguiente_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BotonSiguiente.Click
    End Sub
End Class
```

Aqui en form
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al darle el boton nuevo, se habilitan los textbox para rellenar los datos y al darle guardar se guardan en el Datagridview, pero lo que quiero es que haga lo inverso... Que al darle siguiente se muestre los datos de DataGridView en el textbox (sin seleccionar una casilla)

Comment: DataGridViewTextBoxColumn... No hay Forma de pasar los datos sin seleccionar una casilla??

Comment: Me podrias decir como pls? xd (Sorry por mi ignorancia soy nuevo)

Comment: Intente hacerlo con el siguiente codigo
For Renglones As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            For Columnas As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                MsgBox(Me.DataGridView1.Item(Columnas, Renglones).Value)
            Next
Next

Pero al poner los textbox no me da los datos

Comment: Ese ejemplo es mas que valido como intento! usa el boton [edit] y agregalo en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que jugar con la posición actual de la fila seleccionada, los `Index` y `CurrentCell` del `DataGridView`. Prueba este código, creo que te funcionará:

```
Private Sub BotonSiguiente_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSiguiente.Click

    If Agenda.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        Dim i As Integer = Agenda.CurrentRow.Index + 1

        If i < Agenda.Rows.Count - 1 Then
            TextBoxNombre.Text = Agenda.Item(0, i).Value
            TextBoxTelefono.Text = Agenda.Item(1, i).Value
            TextBoxDireccion.Text = Agenda.Item(2, i).Value

            Agenda.CurrentCell = Agenda.Rows(i).Cells(0)
            Agenda.Rows(i).Selected = True
        ElseIf Agenda.Rows.Count = 2 Then
            TextBoxNombre.Text = Agenda.Item(0, 0).Value
            TextBoxTelefono.Text = Agenda.Item(1, 0).Value
            TextBoxDireccion.Text = Agenda.Item(2, 0).Value

            Agenda.CurrentCell = Agenda.Rows(0).Cells(0)
            Agenda.Rows(0).Selected = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnAtras_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAtras.Click

    If Agenda.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        If Agenda.CurrentRow.Index > 0 Then
            Dim i As Integer = Agenda.CurrentRow.Index - 1

            TextBoxNombre.Text = Agenda.Item(0, i).Value
            TextBoxTelefono.Text = Agenda.Item(1, i).Value
            TextBoxDireccion.Text = Agenda.Item(2, i).Value

            Agenda.CurrentCell = Agenda.Rows(i).Cells(0)
            Agenda.Rows(i).Selected = True
        ElseIf Agenda.Rows.Count = 2 Then
            TextBoxNombre.Text = Agenda.Item(0, 0).Value
            TextBoxTelefono.Text = Agenda.Item(1, 0).Value
            TextBoxDireccion.Text = Agenda.Item(2, 0).Value

            Agenda.CurrentCell = Agenda.Rows(0).Cells(0)
            Agenda.Rows(0).Selected = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias por su repuesta... Probe el codigo pero al dale al boton siguiente o atras no pones los datos en el textbox :c

Comment: Igual, no me salen los datos.... Si no la tengo seleccionada me sale null

Comment: Buenas. Acabo de editar el código. He creado un proyecto similar y lo he probado así que creo debería funcionarte ahora.

Comment: Funciona correctamente Thank You